# Find duplicates and number of times

Tags: c, arrays, duplicates

I have to write a program that finds duplicate in a array and how many times every duplicate is present in the array. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIM 5

int contains (int v[], int dim, int n);

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int i, j, k = 0, found;
    int v[DIM];
    int dup[DIM] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
    {
        printf("Insert element in the array: ");
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
    {
        found = 0;

        if (contains (dup, DIM, v[i]) == 0)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
            {
                if (v[i] == v[j] && (i != j))
                {
                    found ++;
                    dup[k] = v[i];
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (found != 0)
            {
                printf("Element %d has been repeated %d times\n", v[i], found);
            }
        }
    }


    return (0);
}


int contains (int v[], int dim, int n)
{
    int i;
    int found = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] == n)
        {
            found = 1;
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

the program works quite well but I think it is not very efficient. Surely it exists a way to  have a program efficient, isn't it? I mean a way continue using array and not any other structure

Comment: The fast solution is called a hash table. Do you know what that is?

Comment: Yes sure I know what it is since I came from Java but I means another solution  without using hash table

Comment: Ok perfect it is exactly what I wish to know

Comment: @Mazzy If number of nodes are to large then use AVL, it will effectively reduce time

Comment: So you mean to sort at the beginning the array? @larsmans

Comment: Create a priority queue rather than sorting.

Comment: @JimBalter: why a priority queue?

Comment: @larsmans No good reason I guess ... it will be O(n) to build the queue and O(nlogn) to extract the elements, so no better than an O(nlogn) sort + O(n) to count the dups.

Comment: @JimBalter: that's effectively a slow version of heapsort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good hash table solves this problem in linear time. If you don't want to muck with data structures, then here's an O(n lg n) solution in C-like pseudocode:

```
// given: an array a of n integers

sort(a, n);

for (int i = 0;;) {
    int value = a[i];
    int count = 0;

    do {
        i++;
        count++;
    } while (i < n && a[i] == value);

    if (count > 1)
        printf("Element %d has been repeated %d times\n", value, count);
}
```

Sorting can be done with [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). The rest of this algorithm relies on the fact that, after sorting, all duplicates will be grouped together.

Comment: The complexity of this technique is O(n), you should use a dichotomic search (which is O(log n)) in order to find an occurence of your number.

Comment: @nouney The complexity is the complexity of sort, which is at least O(nlogn). And the OP isn't looking for an occurrence of a number.

Comment: @JimBalter I know ... But if you find an occurence of the number of the array you will don't have to start from the index 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should sort (with qsort by example) your array when you filled it, use a dichotomic search to find your number and then search from its index if there are duplicates:

```
array:
0 1 2 5 7 7 48 48 56 72
```

You're searching `7` by example. With a dichotomic search you can find a `7` with O(log n) complexity. Let's call its index IDX (which is equal to 5 in this example)

array:

```
0 1 2 5 7 7 48 48 56 72 103
          ^
          |
         IDX(=5)
```

Now you just have to loop like this:

```
int count = 0;
int idx = 5; // must be finded via a dichotomic search
int toFind = array[idx];

    while (idx >= 0 && array[idx] == toFind)
    {
       ++count;
       --idx;
    }
    idx = 5:
    while (idx < arrayLength)
    {
       ++count;
       ++idx;
    }
```

This solution will work only if you can sort your array and if you want to avoid hashtables.

Comment: The OP is looking for all numbers and how many times they are repeated.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the range of numbers input by the user, here is a O(n) method. Suppose you know that the numbers will be within the range of 0-99.

Here is a pseudo code.

```
//Input the array elements in an array named arr[]

static int freq[101]; //create a static array to initialize all elements to 0

//scan the array arr and increment the counter at index of freq array

for(int i=0;i<(arr.length);i++)
    freq[arr[i]]++;

//Now scan the array named freq and print the frequency of each of the numbers.
for(int i=0;i<101;i++)
    if(freq[i]>0)
         printf("Frequency of %d is:- %d ",i,freq[i]);
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
  int i,j,a[5];

  clrscr();

  printf( "Enter the element in array\n" );
  for( i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
    scanf( "%d", &a[i] );
  }
  for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    for(j=i+1;j<5;j++) {
      if(a[j]==a[i])
        printf("Repeated value is %d",a[i]);
    }
  }

  getch();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you explain how your solution is better than OP's? Code-only answers tend not to be as helpful as if they were accompanied by some explanation.